# Copying the theme style files and images to duplicate the website but with a difference

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options

I have recently downloaded a nulled premium wordpress theme online and have been doing changes to see if I can build the website I want to with the theme. Now that I am satisfied with my result, I want to buy the theme license and give the authors' credit and money that they deserve.

I just am not sure how to copy all the changes that I have made in the theme to the new website with the fresh theme installed. What should I do ? I want to use the same theme but I could not think of a way to copy all the changes. I changed some css settings and it is easy to copy paste that code, also I can copy the product and product categories ettc manually but I dont want to do them all again.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about what kind of modification you added. If you edited any theme file which is strongly discouraged then you have to redo the changes after every theme update. I suggest before changing the theme, create a child theme for your current theme and move file changes there. Then you can change the theme with legit one without headache. Read more about child theme here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 1):

You should have created a child theme and made changes from it.
[Wordpress child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

As you made the direct change to the theme, the only way to pass these changes on to the purchased theme is by copying and pasting.

If the licensed theme is exactly the same as the unlicensed theme (files, code) You only need to replace the files with the ones you changed. However, I believe that there are differences.

Comment: I did the changes to the child theme